# Addons plugins to work in ubuntu 13.04

Tags: counter-strike, linux

How can I use my `addons` amx plugins for Counterstrike 1.6 kreedz/bhop in ubuntu 13.10 as the Windows version of `addons` dosen't work in Linux. Is there any other version available for Linux?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you run the Windows build of Counterstrike in Linux with [Wine](http://www.winehq.org/) you can access Windows addons.  There is a [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8gWLxnb_tkk) (without narration but with a Spanish User Interface) that illustrates this step by step.